# Servlet Access Filters and Roles

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using a Servlet Filter to enforce access control. What is the best way to extend it to have it test for user roles? I can think of several solutions but none are elegant.

Coding a role test is not hard. But how do I pass the role to the filter for the given url?

e.g. In web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>accessControl</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.AccessControlFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>loginPage</param-name>
        <param-value>/login/login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>accessControl</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>accessControl</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/domain/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well exactly thats why always advise against custom Authorization , when there are standards available and frameworks implementing them are available in Plenty.

My fav would be Spring Security.
Check this tutorial , this should put you in right direction

- [Whole bunch of Spring Security Tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/)
- [Spring Security - Access restiction using Roles](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-access-control-example/)

Another widely used alternative , but not quite as elegant and easy  as spring would be

[JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/index.html)